# How to fix this? Problem in style in react js

Tags: css, reactjs, styles

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syCsB.png)
How can i fix this problem. I don't know i try search this problem in google but i don't find solution. And it's very important for me. I try put children like props but it's not working please help me

my sidebar component.

```
import React, { Children, useState } from "react";

import {
  ProSidebar,
  Menu,
  MenuItem,
  SidebarHeader,
  SidebarContent,
} from "react-pro-sidebar";

import { FaList, FaRegHeart, FaTh } from "react-icons/fa";
import { FiHome, FiArrowLeftCircle, FiArrowRightCircle } from "react-icons/fi";
import { RiPencilLine } from "react-icons/ri";
import { BiCog } from "react-icons/bi";

import "react-pro-sidebar/dist/css/styles.css";
import "./Header.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import {pathEdebiyat, pathChemistry, pathEnglish, pathGeography, pathMath, pathPhysics } from "../../Router";

const Header = ({children}) => {
  const [menuCollapse, setMenuCollapse] = useState(false);

  const menuIconClick = () => {
    menuCollapse ? setMenuCollapse(false) : setMenuCollapse(true);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div id="header">
        {/* collapsed props to change menu size using menucollapse state */}
        <ProSidebar collapsed={menuCollapse}>
          <SidebarHeader>
            <div className="logotext">
              <p>{menuCollapse ? "Logo" : "Big Logo"}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="closemenu" onClick={menuIconClick}>
              {menuCollapse ? <FiArrowRightCircle /> : <FiArrowLeftCircle />}
            </div>
          </SidebarHeader>
          <SidebarContent>
            <Menu iconShape="square">
              <MenuItem active={window.location.pathname === pathEdebiyat} icon={<FiHome />}>
                Edebiyat
                <Link to={pathEdebiyat}/>
              </MenuItem>
              <MenuItem icon={<FaList />} active={window.location.pathname === pathMath}>Matematika <Link to={pathMath}/></MenuItem>
              <MenuItem icon={<FaRegHeart />}>Turkmen dili</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem icon={<RiPencilLine />}>Himiya</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem icon={<BiCog />}>Rus DIli</MenuItem>
            </Menu>
          </SidebarContent>
        </ProSidebar>
        <main>{children}</main>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

sidebar styles. I try to use overflow but it isn't help me. And i don't know how i can solve this

```
#header {
    position: absolute;
    width: 220px;
  }
  #header .pro-sidebar {
    height: 100vh;
  }
  #header .closemenu {
    color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    line-height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 22px;
    top: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #header .pro-sidebar {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
  }
  #header .pro-sidebar.collapsed {
    width: 80px;
    min-width: 80px;
  }
  #header .pro-sidebar-inner {
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0.5px 0.866px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  }
  #header .pro-sidebar-inner .pro-sidebar-layout {
    overflow-y: hidden;
  }
  #header .pro-sidebar-inner .pro-sidebar-layout .logotext p {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  #header .pro-sidebar-inner .pro-sidebar-layout ul {
    padding: 0 5px;
  }
  #header .pro-sidebar-inner .pro-sidebar-layout ul .pro-inner-item {
    color: #000;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  #header .pro-sidebar-inner .pro-sidebar-layout ul .pro-inner-item .pro-icon-wrapper {
    background-color: #fbf4cd;
    color: #000;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }
  #header .pro-sidebar-inner .pro-sidebar-layout ul .pro-inner-item .pro-icon-wrapper .pro-item-content {
    color: #000;
  }
  #header .pro-sidebar-inner .pro-sidebar-layout .active {
    background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #fece00 0%, #ffe172 100%);
  }
  #header .logo {
    padding: 20px;
  }
  
  main {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
    html {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  }
```

my router component. Router.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Chemistry from "./components/Chemistry";
import Edebiyat from "./components/Edebiyat";
import English from "./components/English";
import Geography from "./components/Geography";
import Header from "./components/Header/Header";
import Math from "./components/Math";
import Physics from "./components/Physics";

export const pathMath = "/Math";
export const pathPhysics = "/Physics";
export const pathEnglish = "/English";
export const pathGeography = "/Geography";
export const pathChemistry = "/Chemistry";
export const initialPage = "/";
export const pathEdebiyat = "/Edebiyat";

export default function Router() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>


        <Routes>
          <Route path={pathEdebiyat} element={<Edebiyat />} />
          <Route path={pathMath} element={<Math />} />
          <Route path={pathChemistry} element={<Chemistry />} />
          <Route path={pathPhysics} element={<Physics />} />
          <Route path={pathEnglish} element={<English />} />
          <Route path={pathGeography} element={<Geography />} />
        </Routes>


    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```